# Display the value of a smart contract's variable with Truffle External Script

Tags: truffle

I will like to display the value of a variable in an existing smart contract in Truffle.

Here's my script:

```
module.exports = async function(callback) {
const project = artifacts.require("project");
let p = await project.at('0x4514bC8332c94AEE465e7c70B0d0497424A66D67');
console.log(p.methods.state.call());}
```

So I run it hoping that it displays the value of state.

```
truffle exec test.js
```

But all I get is this, with no values displayed:

```
Using network 'development'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `await` before `p.methods.state.call()`.

You can also get rid of the `await` before `project.at`.

And AFAIK, you should use `truffle test` instead of `truffle exec`.

Comment: You are right. When I copy the same codes to my deployment script it actually works. Thank you!